# Long list of PrimeNG Checkboxes destroys the whole page layout

Tags: html, css, angular, primeng, primeng-checkbox

1. Open this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-vovdob)
2. Scroll all the way down
3. Click on one of the last few checkboxes

(This occurs for me on Google Chrome Version 92.0.4515.131 (Official Build) (64-bit) but e.g. NOT on firefox - I did not check other browsers yet)

Result:

- Depending on the screen size, the whole page moves up by a few centimeters, the top no longer being accessible.
- On smaller screen sizes, the whole page is gone and I am left with empty white space.
- You can simulate the screen sizes by just changing the amount of items in the loop. 40 items on 1080p will move the full screen out of reach, 20 items on 1080p will have a little bit still shown. See screenshots below

I can not figure out what I am doing wrong here - this doesnt occur anymore when replacing the p-checkbox with an input type="checkbox". Setting all properties of the p-checkbox also doesnt change this behaviour.

[image: Normal View before scrolling/checking]
[image: View after selecting a checkbox, already 50% of screen empty]
[image: View after selecting a checkbox but with 30 items - whole screen gone]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly I haven't figured out the reason for it but you can add `position: relative`  to your container class.

```css
.content-container {
  position: relative;
}
```

[Check the stackblitz](https://github-vovdob-1jvuiz.stackblitz.io/)

I added it to the `app.component.css` file and placed this line
`styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']` below the `templateUrl` in your `app.component.ts` file.

Comment: Thanks - I went with this solution as it fixed my problem and didnt break any other layouts. However, I still couldnt find or understand the root cause of why this happens

Comment: I haven't checked the root cause yet, but my best guess is that the actual `absolute` position of the check in the checkbox has something to do with it. In addition, depending on the components you use it also happens with the PrimeNG Listbox